# Como guardo en una tupla o lista los valores de un diccionario JSON en Python?

Tags: python, json

Actualmente tengo el siguiente diccionario JSON:

```
tree =
{
    'MADRE': '323', 'reports':
        [{
            'MADRE': '4444', 'reports':
                [{'MADRE': '5'}, {'MADRE': '4'}]
        }, {'MADRE': '3',
            'reports': [{'MADRE': '33'}, {'MADRE': '6'}, {
                'MADRE': '99',
                'reports': [{'MADRE': '233'}]
            }, {'MADRE': '7'}]
        }]
}
```

Lo que quiero obtener es algo parecido a esto:

```
[(323,4444), (323,5), (323, 4), (323, 3), (323, 33), (323, 6), (323, 99), (323, 233), (323, 7)]
```

Es decir obtener el primer elemento y que quede estático de tal forma que tenga *tuplas* con cada valor del diccionario.

De esta forma luego generar una salida para crear un *dataframe*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como lo planteas tu problema se reduce en principio a obtener todos los valores de una clave determinada en el JSON (`dict`) recorriendo todos los posibles niveles de anidamiento. Una posible implementación recursiva, que para esto es bastante simple, podría ser:

```
def find_key(target, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == target:
                yield value

            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                yield from find_key(target, value)

            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    yield from find_key(target, item)

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            yield from find_key(target, item)
```

Se puede hacer de forma iterativa usando una cola, por ejemplo:

```
from collections import deque


def find_key(target, obj):
    queue = deque()
    queue.append(obj)
    while queue:
        obj = queue.pop()
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for key, value in obj.items():
                if key == target:
                    yield value
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    queue.append(value)
                elif isinstance(value, list):
                    queue.extend(reversed(value))
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            queue.extend(reversed(value))
```

La función es un generador, como quieres mantener el primer valor encontrado como primer elemento de las tuplas, puedes hacer algo así:

```
tree = {
    'MADRE': 323, 'reports':
        [{
            'MADRE': 4444, 'reports':
                [{'MADRE': 5}, {'MADRE': 4}]
          },
         {'MADRE': 3,
            'reports': [{'MADRE': 33}, {'MADRE': 6}, {
                'MADRE': 99,
                'reports': [{'MADRE': 233}]
            }, {'MADRE': 7}]
        }]
} 

f_gen = find_key("MADRE", tree)
a = next(f_gen) # Primer valor para la clave
res = [(a, b) for b in f_gen]
```

---

> ```
> >>> res
> [(323, 4444), (323, 5), (323, 4),
>  (323, 3), (323, 33), (323, 6),
>  (323, 99), (323, 233), (323, 7)]
> ```

### Edición

[`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) que permite delegar en un subgenerador se introdujo en Python 3.3, si se usa una versión anterior debemos iterar directamente sobre el generador con un `for in` y usar `yield`, quedando la versión recursiva algo así:

```
def find_key(target, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == target:
                yield value

            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                for item in find_key(target, value):
                    yield item

            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    for r in find_key(target, item):
                        yield r

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            for r in find_key(target, item):
                yield r
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, hice un intercambio para el uso del "from", ya que por la versión del framework o python que uso no era soportado, quedando de esta forma:

Comment: Hola @JulioAlemánMéndez , se me pasó comentar eso, cuando no hay etiquetas especificas de versión suelo dar la respuesta para la versíon más reciente del intérprete. Efectivamente, si usas Python < 3.3 `yield from` no está disponible. He editado la respuesta comentando esto al final.

Comment: Por cierto, dado que eres nuevo por este sitio te informo que puedes aceptar aquellas respuestas que mejor solución den a tus preguntas de forma que sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios para valorar  la utilidad de las mismas. Puedes mirarte [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/15089)  para ver cómo funciona y como hacerlo. Un saludo.